# Calculate mean and bootstrap confidence intervals by group

Tags: r, confidence-interval

How can I calculate a mean and bootstrap CI by group and return the answer as a dataframe?

I have managed to get most of the way but my answer is returned as a list. Reproducible example below. Any help appreciated.

```
library(dplyr); library(Hmisc)

graph <- iris %>% 
+     select(Petal.Length, Species) %>% 
+     group_by(Species) %>% 
+     group_map(~ smean.cl.boot(., conf.int = .95, B = 1000, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `bind_rows` to your attempt.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

iris %>% 
     select(Petal.Length, Species) %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     group_map(~ smean.cl.boot(., conf.int = .95, B = 1000, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     bind_rows()

#   Mean Lower Upper
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1.46  1.42  1.51
#2  4.26  4.13  4.38
#3  5.55  5.4   5.70
```

Or another way would be :

```
iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Length, Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(data = list(smean.cl.boot(cur_data(), conf.int = .95, B = 1000, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(data)

#  Species     Mean Lower Upper
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      1.46  1.42  1.51
#2 versicolor  4.26  4.13  4.39
#3 virginica   5.55  5.40  5.70
```